# Small Confusion about TF

Tags: ros, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if I have a broadcaster like this:

```
void pub_odom::odom_callback(const nav_msgs::Odometry& odom) {

btVector3 Position;
btQuaternion Orientation;
tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster_;
tf::StampedTransform odom_transform;

Position.setValue(odom.pose.pose.position.x,odom.pose.pose.position.y,odom.pose.pose.position.z);
Orientation.setW(odom.pose.pose.orientation.w);
Orientation.setX(odom.pose.pose.orientation.x);
Orientation.setY(odom.pose.pose.orientation.y);
Orientation.setZ(odom.pose.pose.orientation.z);

odom_transform.setOrigin(map_center);
odom_transform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(tf::Vector3(0,0,1),-yaw_init));
odom_transform.stamp_ = odom.header.stamp;
odom_transform.child_frame_id_= "/odom";
odom_transform.frame_id_= "/center_map";
odom_broadcaster_.sendTransform(odom_transform);}
```

How do I visualise its publication on rviz and tf. Do i have to create something like in my launch file in order to visualise it:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="tf_data" args="1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 /odom /another_link 20" />
```

WHen I do it with this launch file I can visualise in tf the tranformation between /odom and /another_link and the transformation is based on args I have given in launch file. How do I get the publication based on the broadcaster and the callback function.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71950/small-confusion-about-tf/) by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can remove the static transform publisher from the launch file, if you want /center_map to be your center in rviz.

In your code do the following:

```
odom_transform.setOrigin(Position);
odom_transform.setRotation(Orientation);
```

In rviz select center_map as the fixed frame.

Hope this works.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on 2013-08-10**:
so I removed the whole line <node pkg="tf" .................   /> from my launch file. I also added the 2 lines that you mentioned into my code. But when I do rostopic list. It does not list tf as a topic now. Why does it not list tf as a topic. Similarly my view_frames return no tf data now. What should I do ?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2013-08-10**:
Could you please update the code in your question, so I can check, if it's correct? Does your callback get called?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `view_frame` to generate a pdf file and see the tf tree. In rviz you can visualise tf axes based on a fixed frame, commonly `/map` frame.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1